# After updating Minecraft: Pocket Edition, there isn't any mobs spawning

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just updated Minecraft: Pocket Edition to 0.7.3. I noticed however, when I'm playing survival mode I don't have any mobs and my life hearts regenerate automatically.

I know about peaceful mode but the new version doesn't have a way to do that. How do I get my mobs back?

Answer (score 4):

You are on Peaceful. Load your save, open the Pause menu, choose **Options** and from the first screen that appears (the **Game** options menu) slide the **Difficulty** slider all the way to the right.

There is no longer a "Peaceful mode" *control*, but there is still Peaceful mode. It is activated by setting the difficulty slider to the left. The difficulty slider now has only two settings: left and right, with no middle setting. Left is Peaceful, right is normal difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this when I updated too. You are in the peaceful mode. To undo this, you pause the game, and move the slider all the way to the right. Voilà!